# Does C# allows pointers?

Tags: c#, pointers, unmanaged

I came across this line,

> C# allows pointers but only in unmanaged code.

From *[Definition of Pointer](http://cplus.about.com/od/introductiontoprogramming/g/pointerdefn.htm)*, I read about this already in C and C++ friend functions. I didn't understand or get further explanations from that site if C# allows pointers...

What is some code for this or an understandable definition?

Comment: [Pointer types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx)

Comment: You can refer to MSDN for explanations about [Unsafe Code and Pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx "Unsafe Code and Pointers") using C#

Comment: C# allows pointers in *unsafe* code, not unmanaged code. You can't write unmanaged code in C#.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque ar this site i read.. http://cplus.about.com/od/introductiontoprogramming/g/pointerdefn.htm

Comment: @user3563106, well, this site is wrong ;)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque  Offically its unsafe code , meaningfully used both words huh .. ty for ur reply

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Well, since you're hung up on the wording, I thought I'd chime in. C# compiles to CIL, which uses the keywords `managed` and `unmanaged` that correspond to "safe and "unsafe". So therefore when you write unsafe code in C#, you're really writing unmanaged code. [See Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) for some examples of CIL with managed and unmanaged code.